# Microsoft Office Interop Excel to Open XML SDK 2.0

Tags: openxml, office-interop, openxml-sdk, excel-interop

I have an Excel 2010 Automation project using Microsoft Office Interop library in C#.NET. But now i need to migrate it to work with Open XML SDK 2.0. Any guidelines or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenXML SDK provides far too many low level access / functions. It consumes some time to master but has huge flexibility.

For starters, use libraries like EPPlus or ExcelPackage. If you have very very large files to process frequently, OpenXML should be best bet.